# Al utilizar base64 sobre un string de bytes recibo el error 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x86 in position 2: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, codificación, base64

Estoy intentando cifrar un archivo a través de una web api que utiliza Flask.

Primero leo los bytes del fichero, lo meto en un json encodeando con base64 y lo envío en un post a la api:

```
with open('/root/Desktop/fichero.txt', 'rb') as outfile:
    datos = outfile.read()


headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post("http://localhost:5000/api/encrypt", json={'file':base64.encode(datos),'alg':'aes256'}, headers=headers)

print r.content
```

Una vez en la api, revierto el proceso de encodeo en `base64` y lo cifro con la biblioteca `PyCrypto`. Finalmente, intento devolver en la respuesta `HTTP` el fichero cifrado de nuevo en un `JSON`;

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

@app.route('/api/encrypt_file', methods=['POST'])
def encrypt_file():

    data = request.json

    data['file'] = base64.b64decode(data['file'])    

    iv = Random.new().read(16)

    cipher = AES.new(key,AES.MODE_CBC,iv)#key es byte string de 32 bits
    fichero_enc= iv + cipher.encrypt(data['file']) 

    return jsonify({'file':base64.b64encode(fichero_enc)}) #aquí salta la excepción
```

El problema aparece cuando intento encodearlo de nuevo en base64 para poder crear el `JSON` de respuesta, que me lanza una excepción de tipo `UnicodeDecodeError`:

```
>> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x86 in position 2: invalid start byte
```

No entiendo por qué ocurre esto si yo en ningún momento realizo ninguna acción con utf8, realmente no entiendo muy bien cómo funciona el encoding/decoding en python.

Comment: Y el problema ocurre cuando haces `base64.b64decode(data['file'])` o cuando haces `base64.b64encode(fichero_enc)`?

Comment: @amenadiel al realizar base64.b64encode(fichero_enc)

Comment: y cómo estás definiendo `ctr`? Estás usando `PyCrypto` y luego `ctr = Crypto.Util.<ALGO>`?

Comment: @amenadiel he editado el post para introducir la parte de código que solicitabas.

Comment: No logro reproducirlo (estoy en un virtualenv con python3 eso sí).  `print(fichero_enc)` muestra un objeto bytes en la forma `b'\xc0x\xf4?Rz\x97\x12\xf8\x8f..` de manera que sí pueden haber secuencias de escape de caracteres no UTF-8 como resultado. En segundo lugar, para usar `jsonify` tuve que castear el resultado a string:   `jsonify({'file': str(base64.b64encode(fichero_enc))})` puesto que me tiraba el error `Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable`. Finalmente, para usar `cipher.encrypt` tuve que añadirle ceros al contenido de `data['file']` para que tuvera un largo múltiplo de 16

Comment: En resumen, detecto esos tres posibles culpables del error

Comment: @amenadiel Yo lo estoy haciendo en python 2.7, es posible que cambie un poco el asunto. En todo caso, lo de añadirle los 0's es porque la longitud del archivo a cifrar ha de ser múltiplo de 16, en mi caso eso lo tengo arreglado y no hay problema. Por otro lado, añado el casteo a str y me sigue fallando, por lo que supongo que el problema está en lo primero que señalabas (también encaja con la excepción que puse en el post). Ahora bien, por qué da problemas con utf-8 si yo intento encodearlo en base64? Y cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: intenta haciendo un base64.b64encode(fichero_enc).decode('utf-8');